# How can I create a PictureBox with close, maximize, and minimize buttons?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, picturebox

I am creating a GUI with C#. I intended to use a ListView to see preview of pictures, and a `PictureBox` to display the full view. I used a `Panel` as parent and placed a `PictureBox` inside of that to have scrollbars appear on the picture box.

What I still can't figure out how to do is to provide close, maximize, and minimize, buttons on the `Panel`, as seen in many GUI applications.

How can I do this? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those other GUI applications probably use a `Form` instead of a `Panel`/`PictureBox`, assuming that they provide maximize, minimize, and close buttons.

You could add your own buttons to the `Panel` control, and then write code in their `Click` event handlers to do whatever you want with the control. This is easy and relatively straight-forward if you just want to be able to close the picture, but it seems like unnecessary work to duplicate *all* of the functions that are built right into a `Form`.

I'd ditch the `Panel` control, add a new `Form` to my project, place the existing `PictureBox` control onto the form that I just added, and go from there. You might want to set the form's [`FormBorderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) property to something like "SizableToolWindow", depending on how you want it to look.

Comment: Incredible that this is the accepted answer, but doesn't qualify as "useful" (and thus merit an upvote).